# A better understanding for separation of concerns. Android; Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I am an Android developer with only 5 months of experience. I am still learning and trying to do my best.

Right now I am interested in concept of `Separation of concerns`. I do understand what it means and I am trying my best to follow it in my android development, however, I found myself a bit confused when I started learning about Clean Architecture.

I would like to show my bit of code, and if, possible, get some feedback on my implementation and its correctness when it comes to `Separation of concerns`

Code [Note: I am using MVVM in this app]:

PopularMoviesFragment:

```
class MoviesPopularFragment : Fragment() {

    private val moviesViewModel: MoviesViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private val adapter = PopularMoviesRecyclerAdapter()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding = FragmentMoviesPopularBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        binding.viewModel = moviesViewModel
        binding.popularMoviesRV.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2)
        binding.popularMoviesRV.adapter = adapter

        moviesViewModel.popularMoviesState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { state ->
            when (state) {
                is PopularMoviesState.Content -> {
                    // TODO: Find a way to deal with this via DataBinding
                    binding.popularMoviesSwipeRefresh.isRefreshing = false
                    binding.progressBarLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.pageNavigation.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                    adapter.submitList(state.response.results)
                }
                is PopularMoviesState.Failure -> {
                    // TODO: Find a way to deal with this via DataBinding
                    binding.popularMoviesSwipeRefresh.isRefreshing = false
                    binding.progressBarLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.pageNavigation.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                    adapter.submitList(state.cachedListOfMovies)
                    showSnackbar(requireView(), getString(R.string.movies_popular_message_viewing_cached_content), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                }
            }
        })

        // TODO: Look into implementing this via DataBinding
        binding.popularMoviesSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
            binding.popularMoviesSwipeRefresh.isRefreshing = true
            moviesViewModel.fetchPopularMovies()
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun showSnackbar(view: View, message: String, length: Int) {
        val snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, message, length)
        snackbar.animationMode = Snackbar.ANIMATION_MODE_SLIDE
        snackbar.setAction(view.context.getString(R.string.alert_dialog_default_button_ok)) { snackbar.dismiss() }
        snackbar.show()
    }
}
```

MoviesViewModel.kt:

```
fun fetchPopularMovies(page: Int = currentPage) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val result = MainRepository.fetchPopularMovies(page = page)

            _popularMoviesState.value = when (result) {

                is PopularMoviesState.Loading -> PopularMoviesState.Loading
                is PopularMoviesState.Content -> {
                    //TODO: Perhaps find a way to work with pages in a better, more isolated way.
                    currentPage = result.response.page
                    PopularMoviesState.Content(result.response)
                }
                is PopularMoviesState.Failure -> {
                    PopularMoviesState.Failure(result.errorMessage, result.cachedListOfMovies)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

MainRepository.kt

```
suspend fun fetchPopularMovies(page: Int = 1) = try {
        val response = IPopularMovies.getInstance().getMovies(page = page)

        if (response.code() == 200) {
            savePopularMoviesToCache(response.body()!!.results)
            PopularMoviesState.Content(response.body()!!)
        } else {
            PopularMoviesState.Failure(response.body()!!.status_message, popularMovieDao.getMovies() ?: listOf())
        }
    } catch (error: Throwable) {
        PopularMoviesState.Failure(error.localizedMessage!!, popularMovieDao.getMovies() ?: listOf())
    }

    private suspend fun savePopularMoviesToCache(listOfMovies: List<PopularMovie>) {
        popularMovieDao.clearTable()
        popularMovieDao.addMovies(listOfMovies)
    }
```

I am mostly interested in `MainRepository` and its implementation of `fetchPopularMovies`
As you can see, this one function does not have only 1 job, in fact, it does multiple things depending on the situation it is in.

1. It fetches movies using Retrofit Interface. -> Exactly what it should do
   Then it either:
   2.1. Saves movies to cache
   or
   2.2. Gets movies from cache

Therefore it does not really do 1 thing as it should if we follow the `Separation of concerns` if I understand correctly.

Here is how I think a correct implementation could look:

1. In MainRepository, create 2 separate functions. 1 for saving movies to cache, 1 for getting movies from cache
2. In ViewModel do the same thing and create 2 separate functions. 1 for saving to cache. 1 for getting from cache
3. In Fragment, where we observe. If success -> call saveCache function in ViewModel
   if Failure -> call getCache in ViewModel

Please give me some feedback on my thought process. I would really appreciate this!

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).